# could not broadcast input array from shape (215280,1306) into shape (215280,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model summary is:
[image]

The data for training are as following by Jupyter Notebook.

[image]

I try to train my model like this.

```
model.fit(x=[input_word_ids, suggestion_ids, intent_encoded], 
          y=click,
          batch_size=64,
          epochs=2)
```

But I got the following error.

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-87-ff46ed631166> in <module>
>       2           y=click,
>       3           batch_size=64,
> ----> 4           epochs=2)
> 
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py
> in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
>      65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
>      66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
> ---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
>      68     finally:
>      69       del filtered_tb
> 
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py
> in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes,
> batch_size, shuffle, **kwargs)
>     654                **kwargs):
>     655     super(ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter, self).__init__(x, y, **kwargs)
> --> 656     x = np.asarray(x)
>     657     if y is not None:
>     658       y = np.asarray(y)
> 
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (215280,1306)
> into shape (215280,)
```

Is there any friend having some suggestions to me? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know a lot about this code, but it seems that you have a 2-D array where it wants a 1-D array.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks for your comment. According to the error information, the error was from an input array with shape (215280, 1306). Only intent_encoded has this shape. Actually, the shape is that I expected. 215280 is the number of samples, every sample is a 1306-D vector.

Comment: Can you show your model code

Comment: Thank you all guys. I fixed it just by changing training samples for X from a list to Dict like the following:
{"input_msg": np.array(input_word_ids),
    "suggestion": np.array(suggestion_ids),
    "intent": np.array(intent_encoded)}
And then, all is OK.

Comment: As a new guy of using Tensorflow, reading the demo code of Tensorflow is very cozy and amazing, but it is really difficult to be skilled in it.